# How to upload files via files tree in GitHub's Atom editor

Tags: file-upload, upload, atom-editor

How can you upload files via TreeView in GitHub's Atom Editor like in FileZilla?

Comment: Why the [tag:github] tag? Do you mean "upload files _to GitHub_"? That's not how Git works…

Comment: The `atom` tag you used for this question is in relation to the XML based syndication format, as this post is about GitHub's Atom Editor I have changed the tag to `atom-editor`. If you are not sure about how to use tags, please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)